# Android prevent restart activity after startActivity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a problem with `startActivity()` methods.

**Problem Structure**

1. Click Link (example, http://google.com) in some TextView, using LinkMovementMethod
2. Callback into `LinkCatcher` class (because some TextView exist almost all activity, so i using outer class)
3. Post event to `MainActivity` using Otto (because it prevent `startActivity outside of activity` problem.)
4. on MainActivity, intent to `Activity B` without any Flag, just one extra (link)
5. When Activity B created, Activity A will destroy and call `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` (i insert some Log.e to my Code, definitely it re-call Log code)

**Tried Methods**

1. Insert android:launchMode="singleInstance" in MainActivity, Activity B
2. Insert android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" in MainActivity (it means, orientation is not problem. i already implement onSaveInstanceState in all activity of my Application) 
   3.remove Step 3. instead of Post event to MainActivity, call startActiivty() in LinkCatcher Class

I tried all methods which i try it. and i don't know why activity is destroy and re-call onCreate (not onResume) even i don't use any finish() methods.

Comment: try freeing up some memory on the device or create an emulator with lots of memory and check if it makes a difference having free RAM so we can exclude the case where android kills activity A. Killing it once sure, but I doubt it android kills the activity on every click and case

Comment: @PopTudor I already using 3GB memory (Galaxy S6) Device, and i also using 2GB memory of emulator. but problem is happened. that's why i don't think this problem happened by memory. (even i using largeHeap option)

Comment: Please post some code for us to look at and check your logcat. This is not standard behaviour, something strange is going on. Also post your manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Because that's how Android is designed-  at any moment an Activity not currently on screen can be killed.  You can't prevent it.  What you can do is account for it-  you can save off any necessary data in onSaveInstanceState, and restore it in onCreate from the Bundle or in onRestoreInstanceState.

Comment: but i think that's something wrong. there's two way to access(using startActivity) Activity B. One is Navigation Drawer, other one is received event from LinkCatcher class, when access by navigation drawer, problem not happened